# How to seed each member of a multiprocessing pool with unique data

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have an array of objects which I want to distribute among n worker
processes to do the job of mapping. What is the best way to accomplish this?
Right now I am seeding a queue with the worker objects and then having each of
the worker processes take one of the worker objects from said queue, however I
feel there should be a more concise way of doing this (maybe by finding a way
to pass unique arguments to each initializer). What I am doing currently seems
like it would be common enough to accomplish using Pool and its various
arguments without the attendant code or (what I perceive to be) the abuse of a
shared queue.

E.G

```
import multiprocessing as mp


objects = [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ]

object_pool = mp.Queue()
for o in objects: object_pool.put(o)

worker_object = None

def init():
    worker_object = Worker(object_pool.get())

def worker(thing):
    return worker_object.transform(thing)

pool = mp.Pool(len(objects), initializer=init)

pool.map(worker, [item 1, item 2,...])
```